# Cookie not saving when switching page

Tags: html, jquery, cookies

So, I'm developing my website and I created 2 html files to have a bilingual website. I created a modal to appear on page load and I'm using cookies to save the user click event on the button inside the modal.

The thing is, when I'm on the first language page and the modal opens up, I click the button and the cookie is saved. But when I switch to the second language page, the modal doesn't appear. When I try the opposite, the modal appears and the cookie is saved on both pages.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong or if this is how it works, first time using cookies. The code:

```html
    <div class="warning_modal">
        <div id="warning_modal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal_content">
                <div class="warning_text">
                    <span>text goes here</span>
                    <p>
                        text goes here
                    </p>
                    <a href="#navigation" class="close">Ok</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
    $('.close').on(click, function(){
        $(".warning_modal").css("display", "none");
        Cookies.set('hide-modal', true, { expires: 7 , path: '', sameSite: 'none', secure: true});
    });
    
    $(function(){
      if(Cookies.get('hide-modal'))
        $(".warning_modal").css("display","none");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a path for your cookie, it'll only work on that same page.
If you set it equal to '/', then it will be available on every page of your domain.
So in your case:

```js
 Cookies.set('hide-modal', true, { expires: 7 , path: '/', sameSite: 'none', secure: true});
```

Comment: Thanks Lex! It makes sense and now it's working. I tought that since I have the same html modal code for both pages, even tho the pages are different because of the language, it would work that way but well, now I get it!